# Arquivo de configuração e/ou Constantes, quando usar?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Atualmente uso constantes para guardar dados de configurações em minha aplicação, mas pesquisando vi que é uma "má prática" pela acoplamento que pode gerar, encontrei algumas perguntas aqui mesmo no StackOverflow falando que o melhor a se fazer é colocar todas as configurações num arquivo (.ini, .xml, etc) e criar uma classe para recuperar esses valores.

1 - Um dos "problemas" que encontrei é quando preciso usar esses valores em views/html.
Por exemplo, no carregamento de css/js, atualmente faço assim:

```
<link rel="..." href="<?=APPURL?>/public/css/...">
```

nesse caso o uso de constantes é correto? até porque essa constante "APPURL" é gerada fora do arquivo de configuração, dentro de outra classe que gera a url amigável de forma dinâmica.

O que construí para substituir o uso de constantes foi o seguinte:

```
// interface para forçar implementações de qualquer configuração que eu faça

interface ConfigHandler {

    function setConfigFile($file);

    function getConfigFile($file);

    function getConfigFileContent($file);

    function get();
}
```

.

```
// classe que recupera as configurações de um json

class jsonConfig implements ConfigHandler {

    private static $configFile = 'config.json';

    static function setConfigFile ($configFile) {

        if(isset($configFile) && is_readable($configFile))
            self::$configFile = $configFile;
        else
            throw new Exception("Arquivo '$configFile' nao encontrado");
    }

    static function getConfigFileContent () {
        return file_get_contents(self::$configFile);
    }

    static function getConfigFile () {
        return self::$configFile;
    }

    static function get($param = null) {

        $configs = json_decode(self::getConfigFileContent(), true);

        if($param)
            return $configs[$param];

        return $configs;
    }
}
```

.

```
 // caso eu precise mudar pra um arquivo xml

    class xmlConfig implements configHandler {...}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
$host = jsonConfig::get('dbhost');
$user = jsonConfig::get('dbuser');
$pass = jsonConfig::get('dbpass');


$PDO = new PDO(...);
```

2 - Nesse caso das classes de configuração, definir uma constante fora da aplicação com o nome do arquivo a ser lido também é correto? caso contrário se eu quisesse mudar o arquivo somente editando a classe?

Answer (score 1):

Eu não costumo usar esse tipo de constante `define( 'FOO' , 'foo' )` justamente por usar uma classe para trabalhar com arquivos de configuração.

No máximo eu uso [constantes em classes](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.constants.php) pois em nada interferem a parte da aplicação.

Nos arquivos de configuração eu defino tudo e tudo fica numa única pasta sem precisar 'garimpar' arquivos na hora de alterar algo que venha precisar - tipo senha de BD, diretório...

Sobre a sua dúvida de `<?=APPURL?>`, a questão não é certo ou errado, mas o que é mais prático. Como citei, trabalho com vários arquivos de configuração, e você pode ter um arquivo único com todas as constantes necessárias tornando fácil a manutenção.

O seu exemplo de uso do config DB está correto, e eu também estenderia seu uso para a parte da `view` e mudaria o valor para o caminho completo do diretório:
`css => xxx/public/css/`, `js => xxx/public/js/`... Vejo que dessa forma é mais fácil aplicar e fazer manutenção deixando o mínimo possível na view.

Em suma, vai de caso a caso.